# Check if User is a fan page ios

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-like

I am using the Facebook SDK to login in my iOS application, and i want to check if the user a fan of our page or note.

I am tried to get the list of liked page of the user by using the permissions, but i didn't see my page in the list:

```
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:                            
                        @"user_birthday",
                        @"user_likes",
                        @"email",
                        nil];
```

Can some one help me to check if user connected is a fan of my page ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you confirm that the user has liked your page using a actual facebook account and not a test account as they don't work.

Answer (score 3):

This code assumes you have the necessary permissions and have the user token:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/likes/19292868552" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"FB_UD %@", error.userInfo);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"FB_LIKES: %@:", result);
        }
    }];
```